# Fresh install of 12.10 instead of upgrading from 10.10 keeps getting stuck

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, uninstall

In order to upgrade Ubuntu from 10.10 to 12.10, I didn't use the update manager but reinstalled it completely.  I made this choice because my old Ubuntu was having problems and I could not login (had login loop).

I had not uninstalled 10.10 before installing 12.10. It started normally but it's getting stuck many times and is taking longer than 5 hours!

Why can this be happening? Can I abort the installing without problems?

Answer (score 3):

Possibilities:

**Problem - Failing hardware:**
Hard disk
RAM
**Solution**
Run a disk health and memory check from the Ultimate Boot CD.

**Problem - Sub-par network connection:**
Packages hang-up downloading or your connection gets mangled
**Solution**
Choose not to download updates or install binary/restricted/extras packages during installation

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10 so I instead aborted the installation without any errors and chose to download the ubuntu .iso file.

I then burned it to a external removable drive and downloaded **linux live** from http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download and run it.

While running the program,insert the usb drive you want to boot ubuntu from and select the .iso file and the program burns it to your usb.

Boot your laptop from external device(1st priority) and install ubuntu.